# Module Not Found - virtual Environment

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, modulenotfounderror

I am getting in error
I am currently using mac

I have created a virtual environment  - name of virtual environment: venv

Even if I have installed the modules I am getting module not found error.

I have tried many things
pip list gave me output which shows that the pandas is installed

I also did -> sys.path

The path to my virtual environment is this :
/Users/nidhivanjare/Desktop/ML/venv

Comment: Have you run `source venv/bin/activate`?

Comment: Please copy and paste the stack trace for the error you're getting

Comment: You may need to use `pip3` install or `python3 -m pip install`.  Also, try `pip3 freeze` to see what's installed or `pip3 freeze --local`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard `venv` needs a dot before the `activate` command, like
`. ./venv/bin/activate`. The first dot is your shell's `source` command.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be because you transferred your virtual environment folder to another location (or you copied it from another computer)

**This is how to fix it:**

1. Open the `/Scripts/activate` file inside your virtual environment folder.
2. Go to the line that has this:

> `VIRTUAL_ENV="$(if [ "$OSTYPE" "==" "cygwin" ]; then cygpath -u 'Z:\<your NEW folder>'; else echo '/Z/<your NEW folder>'; fi;)"`

3. Change the path to the new location of your virtual environment.

   Change it from

> `Z:\<your OLD folder>` **and** `/Z/<your OLD folder>`

```
 to
```

> `Z:\<your NEW folder>` **and** `/Z/<your NEW folder>`

4. If you are using the Command Prompt of Windows, you also have to change the path in the file `/Scripts/activate.bat`

> `set "VIRTUAL_ENV=Z:\<folder>"`